# Delete all folders except one (or more)

Tags: bash, jenkins, sh, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following step that should deletes all folders except `foobar`:

```
node {
    stage('Clean') {
        sh "rm -rf ${WORKSPACE}/path/to/folder/!\\(foobar\\)"
    }
}
```

It generates the following command :

```
rm -rf '/path/to/workspace/path/to/folder/!(foobar)
```

It does nothing. But if I type the command in my terminal (outside Jenkins) without the simple quotes surrounding the path, It works.

Why Jenkins generates simple quotes ? How to remove them so that the command works ?

(I run the Jenkins on OSX)

Answer (score 2):

For deleting workspace (except `foobar` folder) you can also use [cleanWs()](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ws-cleanup/) pipeline method from [Workspace Cleanup](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ws-cleanup) plugin. 
E.g., like this:

```
cleanWs deleteDirs: true, patterns: [[pattern: 'foobar', type: 'EXCLUDE']]
```

See `http://<YOUR_JENKINS_ADDRESS>/<path_to_pipeline_job>/pipeline-syntax/` for generating examples with correct syntax.

For DSL jobs there is [wsCleanup()](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.publisher.MavenPublisherContext.wsCleanup) method (with `excludePattern()` syntax).

Answer (score 0):

The type glob `!(name)` does not work unless you set `shopt -s extglob`
within bash.

Please try:

```
bash -O extglob -c "rm -rf /path/to/workspace/path/to/folder/!(foobar)"
```

As an alternative you can also say:

```
find /path/to/workspace/path/to/folder -type d -mindepth 1 ! -name "foobar" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Please remember to make a backup of folders in advance to avoid the accidental loss of files.